# Domain Groups and EnsureUser

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, office-365-groups

I'm try to add a domain group to a folder using `EnsureUser` and get the following response

> The specified user GROUPNAME could not be found.

The group exists, I've found if I add this group to another item in the site and try again it succeeds. Do I need to add the group to the site and then call ensure user? This seems to occur the very first time. It's almost like it needs to be added to the site first?

If this the case how do I go about achieving this with CSOM

UPDATE :

I've tried the following for ensureuser and still the same:

```
groupname
groupname@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

This is also a Office 365 Group

Comment: is it a security group or a mail distribution group?

Comment: its an Office 365 Group. You can add this group via the UI

Comment: O365 group is only a distribution group not a security group.

Comment: Is there a central point I can get a list of all groups and cross reference it before trying to apply it?

Comment: you will probably need to query azure AD for that

Comment: I thought that might be the case. thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call EnsureUser with the login name in the format 
c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|groupId
where groupId is the id of the group in Azure AD i.e. a guid.

e.g. c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|629b9938-dd1b-4006-97a8-6bb9c4e84ac2

You can get this from the Microsoft or Azure Graph APIs.

Comment: Would this be different for security groups vs a distribution group (which is what the OP asked about)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser` to look up the group id for `EnsureUser`.

Since the API will return all groups starting with the specified name, you might get more than one result and have to make sure you pick the right one.

If you know what type of group you're looking for, you can further restrict the result by specifying a different `PrincipalType`.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
private string LookupGroupName(string groupName)
{
    ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters query = new ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();
    query.AllowEmailAddresses = false;
    query.MaximumEntitySuggestions = 10;
    query.PrincipalType = PrincipalType.All;
    query.PrincipalSource = PrincipalSource.All;
    query.QueryString = groupName;
    ClientResult<String> result = ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser(ctx, query);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var pickerResult = JArray.Parse(result.Value);
    string key = String.Empty;
    foreach (var entry in pickerResult)
    {
        if (entry["DisplayText"].Value<string>().Equals(groupName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            key = entry["Key"].Value<string>();
            break;
        }
    }
    return key;
}
```